# X Window, X Windows, X11

Tags: xorg

while learning shell, I've bumped many times on the term "X Window", so I searched the internet for deffinitions. But I have to admit they were a bit confusing in a sense:

-I know they're the principal GUI where interactions with the keyboard/Mouse happen.

-According to wikipedia, there's a difference between X window and X Windows.

What are they exactly, what's their use? And what does the 'X' stand for?

Comment: [What Is the X Window System](http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2005/08/25/whatisXwindow.html)

Comment: According to wikipedia, there's ***NO*** difference between  X window and X Windows: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System!

Comment: In french wikipedia:

X Window System ou X11 ou simplement X est un environnement graphique de type « fenêtré » qui gère l'interaction homme-machine par l'écran, la souris et le clavier de certains ordinateurs en réseau. Il est souvent appelé X Window à ne pas confondre avec x windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as far as I know:

X Window System = X Windows = X11 (although this can be also name for type of license similar to BSD)

X because it was developed in 80s by MIT X Consortium, but don't know why not Z Consortium :)